# sort date mongodb database using compass

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, spring-boot

how to sort MongoDB data. can I use mongo compass aggregation? my file data have like this `Thu Mar 25 13:10:10 IST 2021`. how to sort this.
I'm using spring boot, react and MongoDB

Comment: Storing date values as string is a design flaw, store **always** proper `Date` objects - then you can also sort it. You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library to convert your string values into `Date` values.

Comment: What is the pattern format of your date??

Comment: this is output date - Mar 25 13:10:10 IST 2021 
i neet to convert 13:10:10 25.03.2021